# How to add bunch of admin accounts to 20 Windows 2012 servers

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012, powershell, group-policy

Is there a quick way to add bunch of admin accounts to 20+ Windows 2012 servers?

It would be way too cumbersome to rdp to each server and add accounts to the local admin group.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If these systems are members of an Active Directory domain you can [use group policy to add a group of admin users](http://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/907-gpo-to-push-out-local-administrators-across-a-domain) to the Local Administrators group.

If these systems are members of a domain but the users are local, you can [use Restricted Groups](https://serverfault.com/questions/227188/is-it-possible-to-add-a-local-user-to-the-admins-group-through-group-policy) to produce the desired effect.

If these computers are not members of an AD domain you can use PowerShell to connect to the systems and adjust the group memberships.

Comment: Both the servers and users are from the same domain. I think I can do powershell. Let me google around for the powershell unless you know a legit link. Thanks

Comment: @Morgan If all of the objects are in the same domain, the standard way to do it would be to use Group Policy.  This will ensure not only that the users are added, but that they remain added when group policy is applied.  A PowerShell script, by contrast, is one-and-done unless you rerun it on a schedule.